# Espresso and Filterable

Tags: listview, android-espresso, android-filterable

I have list view with `Filterable` adapter installed into it. And I am trying to cover this with test using `Espresso` lib. It seems that `Espresso` does not wait for filter operation (as Filter does it in outside of main thread)

Is there any convenient way to register IdlingResource-s for every Filter in project in one place?